# Using Android Volley Library to Post JSON to WCF Restful Service

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, android-volley

My apologies if the same question has been posted some where, but after searching for almost 5 days, one can understand how desperate i am, since most of the answers seem not to give me a solution. Enough of rambling . So, i am trying to post json to a wcf restful web service, using volley. Below are my code snippets

// Android/Volley

```
public void setJsonDataToWebservices(String url){
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("FullName","nathalue Gustava");
            params.put("Id","123");
            params.put("Password","123456789");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create a future request object

        // Create a json request object
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        VolleySingleton.getIntance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
```

Here is my interface for the service

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "simplePostExample")]
    string simplePostExample(Stream jsonStream);
```

...... and here is a method to deserialize the stream and return it a string

```
public string simplePostExample(Stream jsonStream)
        {
            StreamReader reader = null;
            string text = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(jsonStream);
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            return text != null ? text : "String is empty";
        }
```

and here are the error logs
Handling an exception. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: Incoming message for operation 'simplePostExample' (contract 'IDigitizingDataRestfulWebService' with namespace 'http://tempuri.org/') contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Json'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpStreamFormatter.GetStreamFromMessage(Message message, Boolean isRequest)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HttpStreamFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)

Now, dear people of the earth, please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: have you checked the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088463/posting-a-jsonarray-to-wcf-service-from-android

Comment: Hello @toshkini, i tried out the solution on that link, but still got the same error.

Comment: have you checked this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246486/volley-content-type-header-not-updating Specifically I mean overriding getBodyContentType